# HttpWebResponse Stream Read returns zero prematurely

Tags: c#, .net

I have a piece of code similar to this:

```
private void DownloadData(HttpWebResponse response)
{
    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DownloadBlockSize];
    while((int)(stream.Read(buffer, 0, DownloadBlockSize)) > 0)
    {
      .... copy data from buffer to a member etc. ...
    }
}
```

This code is part of an application that runs on various client machines, but error logs are sent to a server. In the error logs, I can see indications that suggest that maybe, rarely, downloads are truncated, but no exception has been thrown.

Is it possible for the `Stream.Read` to return `0` without there being a network error when reading from a `HttpWebResponse` like this?

Comment: What is `data.DownloadStream` and how it relates to `stream`?

Comment: for that matter, what is `data`?

Comment: Sorry about the copy-paste error, which is now hopefully fixed. I realize that it distracts from the real question.